# Tribe Events Calendar copy events

Tags: php, wordpress, events, calendar

I've got 2 Wordpress installations with the tribe events calendar.
I want to copy the events from Website One to Website Two. I want to do that with php.

I found some functions on the tribe events calendar website but couldn't find something like `get_events`.

Does somebody know how to achive my target? Any function suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You simply import and export your events using **WordPress Importer plugin** or **UpdraftPlus plugin**

Comment: I searching for a php based solution because I want to program the logic by myself.